# Syncfusion PDF Single Quotation automatically convert with tab space

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, syncfusion

syncfusion pdf

using semi colon in html text but when pdf report is display Single Quotation is replace with tab space please give any suggestion to solve this problem

for example 
doesn't convert with doesn t

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ’ is special character when we use this special character.
’ not show in pdf report and ’ is replace with space

**To solve this problem in Syncfusion PDF**

when htmlcontent string is ready.

Replace ’ to '

```
htmlContent = htmlContent.ToString().Replace("’", "'");
```